# DNS is not recognised by my network

Tags: dns-hosting

I have recently switched my dns server to a new hosting provider.

I received a new IP and such..

I have created a new file on my www.example.com/newfile.html

on my computer it does not exist,however if I check it on another computer (outside my network) it shows it has switched over.

Can anyone help?

**EDITS**

**old IP**

`123.123.123.1/~myuser/nefile.html` //file does not exist

**new IP**

`123.123.123.2/~myuser/newfile.html` //file does exist and it has "hello world!!!" inside

if i go to `example.com/newfile.html` I see page error instead of "hello world!!!"

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. Please provide more details, such as: Operating System of the server, operating system of the clients, type of network you are on, network settings, etc.

Comment: OS, is linux, and im using windows 7, its a simple network using a router, im not sure about network settings. i have tried to flush my dns , reset my router, etc... somehow my network has associated the previous IP address of the website, with the domain name

Comment: Your question *remains* too vague to answer, we're not magicians, we need information.

Comment: somehow, my pc does not reqognise the new ip associated to the website (my pc only)

Comment: it is a very difficult thing to explain and i don't know alot about networking and hosting if im honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Val, now we've got some information!

Basically your DNS change has not propagated fully everywhere, this can take over a day in some circumstances, it's far from instant and there's little you can do other than flush your own DNS cache and reset your router.

Comment: I switched over 48 hours ago, spoke to my new host they fixed it and then it switched back i am faced again with the same problem

Comment: use 'nslookup {dns name}' to see what your DNS server thinks that entry's IP is, if it's not as you wish then you either need to wait or speak to whoever runs that DNS server.

Comment: ok the website has the old IP address associated to it while using nslookup

Answer (score 0):

You might also check the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc). If it is manually inputted you will have to change it there.
You can also try ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: i have done ipconfig /flush also checked the drivers\etc nothing there to suggest

Comment: I have create a new (windows welcome screen) user name (on my PC) and that seems to have fixed the problem, now i need to know how to fix it